# Difference between a constructor and a zero parameter constructor (Java)

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Can anyone tell me what the difference (conceptually) is between a constructor and a zero parameter constructor is? Example:

How would this implementation affect a program

```
public Person() {
firstName = "UNKNOWN";
lastName = "UNKNOWN";
gender = '?';
retired = false;
age = 0;
address = null;
}
```

compared to say... this:

```
public Person(String f, String l, int a, char g) {
firstName = f;
lastName = l;
age = a;
gender = g;
retired = false;
address = null;
}
```

edit: please ignore the number of parameters...

Comment: What is your understanding about a constructor, in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't define a constructor for a class, a default parameterless constructor is automatically created by the compiler. The default constructor calls the default parent constructor (super()) and initializes all instance variables to default value (zero for numeric types, null for object references, and false for booleans).

Default constructor is created only if there are no constructors. If you define any constructor for your class, no default constructor is automatically created.

> Can anyone tell me what the difference (conceptually) is between a constructor and a zero parameter constructor is?

**No difference.**

Answer (score 2):

Also, a good style is to have only one constructor that does all the real work, even if you have more than one constructor. The term *designated constructor* comes from Objective-C, but it's still a good idea.  Suppose you write this:

```
public Person(String f, String l, int a, char g) {
        // Use more expressive argument names.
    firstName = f;
    lastName = l;
    age = a;
    gender = g;
    retired = false;
    address = null;
}
```

Then, rewrite your no-argument constructor as

```
public Person() {
    this(null, null, 0, '?');
        // Invoke the designated constructor with those arguments.
    retired = false;
    address = null;
}
```

If the first statement of a constructor is `this(...)`, then the constructor is invoking one of the other constructors of the class. Similarly, if the first statement of a constructor is `super(...)`, then one is invoking a constructor of the parent class. If one does neither, than `super()` is assumed.

Then, since `retired` and `address` is set the same way in both constructors, initialize them in their declarations:

```
private boolean retired = false;
private String address = null;  // If it's a String; it could be its own object type.
```

And then, since `false` and `null` are the default values for instance variable initialization, replace those two lines with:

```
private boolean retired;
private String address;
```

Later on, you can add error checking. For example, people do not have negative ages, so inserting the statement

```
if (a < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("A Person cannot have a negative age: "
       + a);
}
```

at the beginning of the designated constructor would be useful. This way, you need do that only once.

When you learn about Java enums, you can then make your gender variable more precise by writing one:

```
// Gender is a grammatical term, Sex is a biological term.
public enum Sex {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

and using `Sex` instead of `char` for your `gender` variable.

Answer (score 0):

A zero-parameters constructor will be auto-created when there are no other constructors defined.
Constructors with parameters are used for a customized initialization of objects.

Answer (score 0):

For the first constructor, any time that you want to instantiate a `Person`, it will always start with the values defined in the constructor.  You will have to use setters to modify that.

For the second constructor, any time that you want to instantiate a `Person`, you must pass through the appropriate parameters.  It means that you can create your objects without having to use a setter to change the value later on.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't define a constructor, the default constructor (which has no parameters) will be generated by default.
2. If you have any user-defined constructor, the default constructor will no be generated at all.
3. whatever, you need a constructor unless your class is utility class.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is called when instantiating an object.  A zero parameter (or "no-arg") constructor is one that requires no arguments.  A class can have multiple constructors, each with different arguments.

Constructors without arguments are particularly helpful for tools that use reflection to populate an object's properties.  The default no-arg constructor is used to construct the object, then its properties are populated by matching the names used in their setters (aka mutators).

Constructors with arguments are especially well suited for creating immutable objects.  The object can be populated once when it is created, and then is guaranteed to not change (provided all the properties are similarly immutable).

Answer (score 0):

**first if you don't have statement constructor the class can aoto create constructor but this constructor not parameter and and initializes all instance variables to default value (zero for numeric types, null for object references, and false for booleans)** *like this:*

```
public Person() {
firstName = null;
lastName = null;
gender = null;
retired = false;
age = 0;
address = null;
}
```

**but you can override this constructor** *like this:*

```
public Person() {
firstName = "firstName";
lastName = "lastName";
gender = '?';
retired = true;
age = 0;
address = "someAddress";
}
```

**and overload this constructor** *like this:*

```
public Person(String f, String l, int a, char g) {
firstName = f;
lastName = l;
age = a;
gender = g;
retired = false;
address = null;
}'
```